# Queries using WP_Query have stopped working on Archive pages since 5.2 upgrade

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Archive pages have stopped executing WP_Query queries since 5.2 upgrade

I have a site that has been running for a year that uses several custom content types and content archives that use templates eg archive-meeting.php, archive-news.php

These templates use WP_Query to generate lists of custom posts.

Recently (since 5.2 upgrade) they have stopped working and the WP_Query calls show no results.

In archive-venue.php

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'venue' ),
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1 ,
    'orderby'                => 'title',
);
global $post;
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {....
```

This was working until recently. It is the same with custom post-types and non-custom. Other code in the template is working OK.

Copying the exact same code into a standard page template (ie not an archive template)  works fine. It seems to be only the case in archive pages.

It seems that the SQL code returned by the Query is different in an archive page:-

**Called in an archive page eg archive-venue.php**

```
  ["request"]=>
  string(412) "SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'venue' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'venue' AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'meeting' AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'hospital' AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'news' AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'school-information' AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'carousel'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC "
  ["posts"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
```

**Called in a non archive page eg temppage.php**

```
 ["request"]=>
  string(188) "SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'venue' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC "
  ["posts"]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    object(WP_Post)#14701 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(4979)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(3) "124"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2019-05-01 11:08:44"
```

The SQL code generated in the archive template contains two conflicting clauses...

> WHERE ....wp_posts.post_type = 'venue' .... AND wp_posts.post_type <> 'venue'

Comment: There is some changes in looking in WordPress 5.2. Not sure if this is the cause but you may want to check this. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/05/07/changes-to-post-globals-setup-and-usage-in-get_the_content-and-related-functions-in-wordpress-5-2/

Comment: Thanks, not sure whether this is relevant. It seems to be the WP_Query is generating the wrong SQL.